# More elegant syntax for pandas filter (passing a function)?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to do the following in pandas which I would do in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = value
```

I was thinking I could use something similar to an `apply` or `map` with a similar interface. Something like:

```
def filter_func(row):
    if row['name'] == 'Bob':
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
df.filter(filter_func, axis=1)
```

Similar to how I can do:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(apply_func, axis=1)
```

Is there a way to do something similar so that it only returns the rows where `name='Bob'` ?

---

The strangest thing is the pandas `filter` function says:

> Note that this routine does not filter a dataframe on its contents. The filter is applied to the labels of the index.

That seems to me like quite a useless way to make use of a `filter` ?

Comment: Do you mean [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)? `df.query('name == "Bob"')`?

Comment: @ALollz sure but to be able to pass a function to `query` (or whatever the method is), and get a boolean back

Comment: As an aside, my motivation for wanting this was so that I could avoid naming the result I wanted to filter... because state is bad. E.g. `(df["x"] ** 2 - df["y"]) % 2 == 0).filter(bool).indexes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with

```
df_filter = df[df['name'] == 'Bob']
```

For sql in operation we have `isin`

```
#SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN ('A','B')
df_filter = df[df['name'].isin('A','B)]
```

---

`filter` is named badly , which is the filter for columns, or when we do `groupby filter`

Comment: right, what would be the closest syntax for passing a **function** though?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 filter is named badly,trust me you are not the only one confused with it.:-)

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 what do you mean? Passing a function to *what*?

Comment: @BEN_YO it's not that confusing if you understand that `pandas` data structures act like mappings, and generally with mappings you work with the keys, e.g. with a dict, `foo in mydict` checks if `foo` is in the keys, similarly, `foo in my_df` checks if `foo` is in the column index, the "info axis". Similarly, `foo in my_series` checks the index.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga from the function itself name a function filter however does not filter the dataframe with it value , looks confused to me

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm just looking for the equivalent of `apply` for a filter that would filter out the rows I don't want.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 there isn't one, you can always `.apply` to create a boolean array then use that for boolean selection. But you should be *trying to avoid* apply, not looking for ways to use it more.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, why do you save avoid `apply`, because pandas/numpy should have vectorized/optimized functions for most of the query operations?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 yes, check with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 yw :-) always keep in mind , if you do not really need apply , try not use it

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 because `.apply` is a stop-gap when you cannot vectorize what you are trying to do. More recent versions have improved it somewhat, CYthonizing the looping I believe, but it is still less than ideal, although still useful.

Comment: In particular, `.apply` is bad along the `axis=1`, it creates a whole `pd.Series` object to represent the row and that's what the function get's passed as an argument.  [Here is a great, detailed question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) EDIT: in particular, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/5014455)